# Date parameter is not fetching record as per giving date

Tags: sql-server-2014

```
CREATE TABLE #SalesOrder (OrderNo INT,Order_Ref_No VARCHAR(50), Order_date date,Status Varchar(50));
CREATE TABLE #OrderDetail (IDOD INT,OrderNO int,CodeItem int,orderqty int);
CREATE TABLE #Sections (SecID INT,Secnam VARCHAR(50));
CREATE TABLE #ItemMasterFile(CodeItem INT,Descriptionitem VARCHAR(50),SecID INT,weight int);
CREATE TABLE #Probale(BID INT,CodeItem INT,prdQTY INT,Orderno int,weight int,Entrydate DATETIME,DelID int);
INSERT INTO #Sections VALUES(1,'HR'),(2,'Baby'),(3,'Ladies'),(4,'Mix Rammage'),(5,'T-Shirst'),(6,'Scrap'),(7,'Scrit'),(8,'Men'),(9,'HHR'),(10,'Sports'),(11,'m-HR'),(12,'M-Baby'),(13,'M-Ladies'),(14,'M-Mix Rammage'),(15,'m--Shirst'),(16,'M-Scrap'),(17,'M-Scrit'),(18,'M-Men'),(19,'M-HHR'),(20,'M-Sports');

INSERT INTO #ItemMasterFile VALUES
  (1,'A',1,100)
, (2,'B',2,100)
, (3,'C',3,100)
, (4,'D',4,100)
, (5,'e',5,100)
, (6,'f',6,100)
, (7,'g',4,100)
, (8,'h',4,100)
, (9,'K',2,100)
, (10,'L',4,100)
, (11,'M',2,100);


INSERT INTO #Probale VALUES 
   (1,1,1,001,100,'01-06-2019',null)
, (2,3,1,001,200,'02-06-2019',null)
, (3,11,1,002,200,'03-06-2019',null)
, (4,10,1,002,200,'08-06-2019',null)
, (4,1,1,003,200,'08-06-2019',null)
, (4,3,1,003,200,'08-06-2019',null);

INSERT INTO #SalesOrder VALUES(001,'A_01','01-05-2019','Open')
, (002,'B_01','01-05-2019','Open')
, (003,'C_01','01-05-2019','Open');

INSERT INTO #OrderDetail VALUES
  (1,001,1,5)
, (2,001,2,3)
, (3,001,3,2)
, (4,002,10,4)
, (5,002,11,3)
, (6,002,3,2)
, (7,003,1,4)
, (8,003,2,3)
, (9,003,3,2);

declare @fromdate date='2019-01-06'
declare @todate date='2019-01-06'
declare @columns varchar(max)
declare @convert varchar(max)
select   @columns = stuff (( select distinct'],[' +  Cast(S.Order_Ref_No AS Varchar(10))
                    from #Probale P inner join #salesorder S on S.OrderNo=P.orderno where  P.Entrydate between @fromdate and  @todate
 and P.DelID is null and S.status ='Open'
                  
                    for xml path('')), 1, 2, '') + ']'


set @convert =
('select * from (select S.Order_Ref_No,P.codeitem,P.prdqty from #Probale P inner join #salesorder S on S.OrderNo=P.orderno where  P.DelID is null 

 ) smallbale
    pivot(sum(prdqty) for Order_Ref_No
    in ('+@columns+')) as pivottable')


execute (@convert)


drop table #SalesOrder
drop table #OrderDetail
drop table #Sections
drop table #ItemMasterFile
drop table #Probale
```

[image: ouput]

Comment: first june 2019, and insert date in this format '2019-05-07'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *insert date in this format '2019-05-07'*

But you're not inserting a date in that (also unsafe) format. From the question:

```
INSERT INTO #Probale VALUES 
   (1,1,1,001,100,'01-06-2019',null)
```

You shouldn't be using `yyyy-mm-dd` (which you do in other parts of the script), and you definitely shouldn't be using `mm-dd-yyyy` or `dd-mm-yyyy`. We have standards exactly because we need to avoid this ambiguity (if I didn't know whether you meant June 1 or Jan 6, how can SQL Server?). This isn't the source of your problem, but it's not helping. You need to fix this and always specify whole dates using `yyyymmmdd`.

On to your query logic. Your pivot ends up being:

```
select * from (select S.Order_Ref_No,P.codeitem,P.prdqty from #Probale P 
inner join #salesorder S on S.OrderNo=P.orderno where  P.DelID is null 

 ) smallbale
    pivot(sum(prdqty) for Order_Ref_No
    in ([A_01])) as pivottable
```

This is not correct if you still want to filter on date, because it's getting the sum of all quantities for that order reference number, not just the ones that happened on the specified date (and if you look at the rows in `#Probale` from order 1, there are two rows, one from June 2).

You're going to have to declare your dates correctly and unambiguously throughout your script (see [this](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5206/sql-server-datetime-best-practices/) and [this](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)), and switch to using [`sp_executesql` instead of `EXEC()`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql) so you can safely pass the date parameters into the dynamic SQL. This isn't fixing your entire script but should be enough to help you solve.

```
declare @fromdate date = '20190601', -- June 1st, no question.
        @todate   date = '20190601', -- fix other dates too!
        @columns  nvarchar(max),     -- these should be Unicode
        @convert  nvarchar(max);     -- this has to be Unicode 

select @columns = stuff (( select distinct '],[' + Cast(S.Order_Ref_No AS Varchar(10))
     from #Probale P inner join #salesorder S on S.OrderNo = P.orderno 
     where  P.Entrydate >= @fromdate 
       and  P.Entrydate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @todate)
     and P.DelID is null and S.status = 'Open'
     for xml path('')), 1, 2, '') + ']';

SET @convert = N'select * from (select S.Order_Ref_No,P.codeitem,P.prdqty 
   from #Probale P 
   inner join #salesorder S on S.OrderNo = P.orderno 
   where  P.DelID is null -- missing status = 'Open' too, maybe
   AND P.Entrydate >= @datefrom 
   AND P.Entrydate < DATEADD(DAY, 1, @dateto)
 ) smallbale
 pivot(sum(prdqty) for Order_Ref_No in ('+@columns+')) as pivottable';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @convert, N'@datefrom date, @dateto date', @datefrom, @dateto;
```

You might also find this post on `BETWEEN` useful - this is a bad form to use for date range queries, even when you're only using the `date` data type today, because it sets bad precedent/example and doesn't protect you from future data type changes:

- [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)